# Status Flag In Assembly8086

Tags: assembly, flags

I am taking an undergraduate class in assembly right now. I have some discrepancies with how the TA graded my assignment. I was only testing the status of the carry, zero, sign, and overflow flags.

Here is one of the status flag problems I got wrong:

```
mov ah, 255
mov al, -1
cmp ah, al
```

My Solutions: `CF=0, ZF=1, SF=0, OF=0`

His solutions: `CF=0, ZF=0, SF=1, OF=1`

Can someone please help me verify which is correct? I don't think mine are wrong but if they are can you explain what answer is correct?

Comment: You answer is correct. If you're running windows, you may be able to verify this by opening a dos console window, run debug, then enter "a100" to enter the instructions manually: mov ah,ff | mov al,ff | cmp ah,al | nop | <enter> |, then g=100,106 to run the code. It will show the flags as: NV (OF=0), ... , PL (SF=0), ZR (ZF=1), NC (CF=0).  Enter q to exit debug. In case you're wondering PE is even parity (PF=1), PO is odd parity (PF=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get running this on VC 2013 (caveat, 32 bit inline assembly in C++)

Before the 3 instructions, the flags are:

```
OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 0 PE = 0 CY = 0
```

After the 3 instructions

```
OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 1 AC = 0 PE = 1 CY = 0
```

Where the flags registers are as [defined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwydd1t7(v=vs.85).aspx)

Interpreted as Parity Set, Carry not set, zero is set, sign is not set, overflow is not set.

Which seems to corroborate YOUR solution.
The disassembly I get:

```
__asm {
    mov ah, 255
00FC13CE  mov         ah,0FFh  
    mov al, -1
00FC13D0  mov         al,0FFh  
    cmp ah, al
00FC13D2  cmp         ah,al  
}
```

My 8086 is terribly rusty, but FWIW:

- <del>It is unlikely that the [Sign Flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_flag) would be set given there are no arithmetic, shift or logical operations.</del> See @Jonathon's answer.
- `mov` is done on the literals -1 (255) and 255  which wouldn't trigger overflow (no flags are set).
- The zero flag should be set given the equality of `255` and `-1` in an 8 bit register.

So I'm guessing the TA might have copy pasted the wrong answer somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, the goal of the assignment was to do it by hand but i'm pretty sure the TA failed to convert the numbers based on the range they fall in and the flag we were testing. And its obvious he didn't check his answers with any other method.

Comment: Your first two bullets are incorrect. As per my answer, `CMP` sets the flags as if a `SUB` was performed, so both `CF` and `OF` *could* be set, if there was a signed/unsigned overflow.  Also, `MOV` does not set any flags.  It doesn't make sense for a register-loading instruction to ever overflow anyway.

Comment: Thanks - my point 1 was indeed wrong, and point 2 was sloppy. Your answer is very detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are indeed correct.

---

Volume 1 of the [Intel Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) describes each of the flags:

> **CF (bit 0) Carry flag** — Set if an arithmetic operation generates a carry or a borrow out of the most-significant bit of the result; cleared otherwise. This flag indicates an overflow condition for unsigned-integer arithmetic.
>
> **ZF (bit 6) Zero flag** — Set if the result is zero; cleared otherwise.
>
> **SF (bit 7) Sign flag** — Set equal to the most-significant bit of the result, which is the sign bit of a signed integer. (0 indicates a positive value and 1 indicates a negative value.)
>
> **OF (bit 11) Overflow flag** — Set if the integer result is too large a positive number or too small a negative number (excluding the sign-bit) to fit in the destination operand; cleared otherwise. This flag indicates an overflow condition for signed-integer (two’s complement)  arithmetic.

The flags in your code are set by the `cmp` instruction, which the Instruction Set Reference Vol 2 says:

> Compares the first source operand with the second source operand and sets the
>   status flags in the EFLAGS register according to the results. The comparison is
>   performed by subtracting the second operand from the first operand and then setting
>   the status flags in the same manner as the SUB instruction.
>
> The SUB instruction performs integer subtraction. It evaluates the result for both
>   signed and unsigned integer operands and sets the OF and CF flags to indicate an
>   overflow in the signed or unsigned result, respectively. The SF flag indicates the sign
>   of the signed result.

First we observe that `al` and `ah` both have the same value: All eight bits are `1`.

Since a `CMP` sets the flags like `SUB`, we just evaluate `0xFF - 0xFF`, which is of course zero.

**OF,CF** - There is no overflow, so `OF=0` and `CF=0`.

**ZF** - The answer is zero, so `ZF=1`.

**SF** - The answer is zero, so `SF=0`.

---

Just to confirm, here's some test code (for GCC):

**flags.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((noinline))
static long test(void)
{
    long ret;

    asm ("mov   $255, %%ah\n\t"
         "mov   $-1,  %%al\n\t"
         "cmp   %%ah, %%al\n\t"

         "pushf\n\t"
         "pop   %0\n\t"
        : "=r" (ret)    /* output  */
        :               /* input   */
        : "%eax"        /* clobber */
    );

    return ret;

}

static void describe_EFLAGS(long flags)
{
    printf("EFLAGS: 0x%X\n", flags);
    printf("    CF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<0)) > 0);
    printf("    PF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<2)) > 0);
    printf("    AF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<4)) > 0);
    printf("    ZF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<6)) > 0);
    printf("    SF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<7)) > 0);
    printf("    TF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<8)) > 0);
    printf("    IF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<9)) > 0);
    printf("    DF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<10)) > 0);
    printf("    OF: %d\n", (flags & (1<<11)) > 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    long flags = test();

    describe_EFLAGS(flags);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ gcc flags.c && ./a.out
EFLAGS: 0x246
    CF: 0
    PF: 1
    AF: 0
    ZF: 1
    SF: 0
    TF: 0
    IF: 1
    DF: 0
    OF: 0
```

**Reference:**

- [FLAGS register (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)